# What time-zone is Cross Validated located in

Tags: support

It would seen that Cross Validated's time zone is somewhere east of Saskatchewan as the dates change on the site sooner than they do for me. Would be nice to know what time zone is being used for logging scores etc.

Comment: [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

Comment: The whole SE network operates by UTC. Indeed you may have noticed that if you hover over things that say "3 hours ago" or whatever, most will give a time with "Z"  at the end (e.g. you asked this Q at `2016-09-23 20:25:52Z` -- stands for "Zulu time", which means almost the same thing as UTC and its abbreviation is sometimes used as a shorthand for UTC). However, many things that update once per day on site happen at times other than 0:00 Z (e.g. some things like checking for whether you achieved a particular badge might happen at a more-or-less random time between about 2:00Z and 3:00Z).

Comment: @Glen_b Wow, I have been wondering about this "Z" for a long time. Zulu time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UTC: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time

[image]